# How to remove input watermark if the field is not empty?

Tags: jquery, drupal, input, watermark

i have this code to add watermark on the input. It is the input for page title. Everything works ok. I write the caption, watermark disappears (that's right). But if I'm editing this content, my title disappears and the watermark is back again. Why watermark returns when the input field contains content?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var watermark = 'Write your city + state (separated by commas)';

    //init, set watermark text and class
    $('#edit-title').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');

    //if blur and no value inside, set watermark text and class again.
    $('#edit-title').blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
        }
    });

    //if focus and text is watermrk, set it to empty and remove the watermark class
    $('#edit-title').focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == watermark){
            $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Sorry for my english. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Do you realize that all [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) support the placeholder attribute? `<input type="text" placeholder="I am placeholder" />` There is no need to code this unless you are supporting old versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for is call **Placeholder**. It was add in HTML5 and all major web browser support it.

[Here you have its definitions and usage.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

You don't need to use JS in order to archive this.

Greetings

Comment: Of course, I know the placeholder. Let's say that I can not insert a placeholder to Input. How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306220/how-to-implement-placeholder-text-on-input-elements-using-jquery

Comment: Is it bug? Where is the problem? Why watermark rewrites headline after editing saved article?

Comment: try: 
        if ($(this).val() != ""){
            $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
        }